# How to upload a zip file using Java?

Tags: java, javascript, dwr

I trying to upload a zip file. In my project i am using DWR in the client side and Java in server side. As i have seen in DWR tutorials for uploading data(Its not in their website. They are providing it with dwr.rar bundle) they getting input by the below lines.

```
var image = dwr.util.getValue('uploadImage');
var file = dwr.util.getValue('uploadFile');
var color = dwr.util.getValue('color');
```

> dwr.util.getValue() is a utility to get the value of any element, in this case a file object.//Mentioned in the tutorial.

So, i get a zip file using that utility by the below code.

**Javascript:**

```
function uploadZip(){
var file = dwr.util.getValue("uploadFile");
dwr.util.setValue("uploadFile", null);
DataUpload.uploadData(file, function(data){
    if(data != null){
        $("#zipURL").html("<p>Upload Completed!!!</p>");
        $("#zipURL").append("Location: "+data.path2);
    }
});
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>ZIP Uploader
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td>Select File: </td><td><input type="file" id="uploadFile" /></td>
<tr><td><input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="uploadZip()" /></td></tr>    </table>
<div id="result"><span id="imgURL"></span>
<span id="zipURL"></span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**The Java Code is:**

```
public class DataUpload {
private static String DATA_STORE_LOC = "D:/BeenodData/Trials/";

public Path uploadData(InputStream file) throws IOException{//In the tutorial the 
          //parameters are in type of BufferedImage & String. 
          //They used it for image and text file respectively.
          //In an another example(out of DWR site) they used InputStream for receiving
          //image

    try {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int c;
    File f2 = new File(DATA_STORE_LOC+dat+".zip");
    path.setPath2(DATA_STORE_LOC+dat+".zip");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f2);
    c = file.read();
    System.out.println(c);
    while ((c = file.read()) != -1) {
        fos.write(c);
         }
    file.close();
    fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return path;

}
```

This code runs without error. But the output is a Empty zip file. I know i doing something wrong. I unable to find that.

> Actually, i am receiving a zip file as
>   InputStream.
>
> How should i have to *write* a
>   InputStream(a zip file) to a zip.file
>   using java?
>
> What will happen if i set the java
>   method parameter as `ZipFile file`? I
>   didnt tried it, yet because, i am
>   still searching a good tutorial to
>   learn about it.

Any Suggestion or Links would be more appreciative!!!!!
Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: can you please explain to me why i still the fakepath even after using dwr.util.getValue("file").

Comment: Sorry, i am not able to understand you? What is fakepath means in terms of DWR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have 2 examples about creating a ZIP file:

[http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180_*File/0601*_ZipOutputStream.htm](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/0601__ZipOutputStream.htm)

Here is an example about reading a ZIP file:

http://www.kodejava.org/examples/334.html

Answer (score 0):

I have also implemented the Same kind of backend Code in Java, and I was facing the same Issue of Zip file being made, but its content being empty.

Later I found that the Request I was making to API, in that the file I was Attaching was not in `--data-binary` format. So, I then made the request in this Format.

```
curl --data-binary @"/mnt/c/checknew.zip" http://localhost/api/upload
```

I am not sure what request format you are making either in `multipart/form-data` or `Base-64` encoded.

My code worked when I made a Base-64 encoded Request (i.e `--data-binary`)