# how to upload a image file in java

Tags: java, image-uploading

I want to upload an Image File on click of the Image as we see in facebook in Java.
Can anyone suggest me the way to do it? I am using GlassFish Server,Netbeans ide 6.8

Answer (score 1):

Look into Jakarta Commons FileUpload.

Answer (score 1):

Simple file upload code: [JSP](http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/javaserver-pages/uploading-file-using-jsp.html)

```
..........
<form action="upload.jsp"
  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  Select a file: 
  <input type="file" name="first" />

  <br />
  <input type="submit" name="button" value="upload" />

</form>
..........

The page processing request with file encoded:
<%@page contentType="text/html;"%>

<%@page import="java.util.Hashtable"%>
<%@page import="javazoom.upload.MultipartFormDataRequest" %>

...........

<%
  try {
    // decode source request:
    MultipartFormDataRequest data = 
       new MultipartFormDataRequest(request);

    // get the files uploaded:
    Hashtable files = data.getFiles();

    if (! files.isEmpty()) {
      // do something with collection of files uploaded;
      ........
    } else {
      throw new IllegalStateException("No files supplied");
    }
  } catch (RuntimeException error) {

    // set error flag in session:
    request.getSession().setAttribute("error", error);

    // throw its further to print in error-page:
    throw error;
  }
%>
...........
```

2. Pure [java applet implementation - JumpLoader](http://www.jumploader.com/index.html)
3. I would recommend: Javascript+Java. Here is a [stackoverflow.com question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158331/how-to-upload-a-zip-file-using-java).